Defining properties through setters and getters returns Error TS2345: Argument of type is missing the following properties
I have an Angular project in which I defined some classes: Classroom, Student and Address. The problem in Angular when I use the bidirectional binding in edit-student-component.html where an address reference is null or undefined it does not work anymore.
<span  class="field mr-3">
  <input pInputText id="student-address-street" placeholder="Student Street" [(ngModel)]="selected.address.street"/>
</span>

This code throws an error in case address is null or undefined, so i thought I would define setters and getters to get and set the student address.
export class Classroom {
  id: number
  students : Student[];
}

export class Student {
  id: number
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
  age: number

  get address() : Address {
    if (this.address) {
      return this.address
    } else {
      return new Address()
    }
  }

  set address(address: Address) {
    if (address) {
      this.address = address
    } else {
      this.address = new Address()
    }
  }
}

export class Address {
  id: number
  street: string
  city: string
  country: string
  postcode: string
}

However when I do this I get a compile error in the student-edit-component.ts at this line:
const observer: Observer<Student> = {
  next:  (data: any)  => {
    let index = this.students.indexOf(this.selectedStudent)
    this.students.splice(index, 1, {...this.editStudent})    <<<<<<< erronous line 
    // this.editStudent is the selected student which is beeing edited  
    ...

TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: number; firstname: string; lastname: string; age: number;}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Student'.  
Type '{ id: number; firstname: string; lastname: string; age: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'student': address

I don't understand how to deal with optional references in bidirectional binding in Angular. Using the optional operator ? does not work in bidirectional binding an i dont like using if else block to implement the different use case of when is defined else do.

but both your setter and getter are recursive. also getters aren't copied with {...student} syntax, so typescript doesn't allow you to assign instance of object(not a class instance) to Student, which looks correct to me.

@Andrei where does recursivity come from ? does calling this.address in the constructor gets converted to getAddress() ? i've seen in some docs/tutorials that getters and setters are normally implemented by defining the fields with underscore  like private _field: string but this way the json to object mapping won't work out the box.

if object has get address() {return 20;} then referencing console.log(obj.address) will call this getter. so will the referece this.address do. there is no explicit constructor in the provided code, but getter references getter, and setter references both getter(in if condition) and setter. I dont't think I understand what json mapping you'd like to achieve

@Andre thanks, i get it now. What i need to do is call a backend service which returns a result of all students in a classroom in json format {id: 1, students : [{id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", .. }, { id: 2, firstname:..}]} which i receive through the observable which maps the result items to the Typescript object Student and set the list result in the students array of the component.

@Andrei, indeed i got a Maximum call stack size exceeded because of the setter and getter
